# In processing, how can I stop sketch playing notes after a certain duration ?

Tags: java, processing, midi

How can I alter the setup() method shown above so that instead of playing just one note it does the following:- it randomly generates a float value between 0 and 10 and then plays as many notes as can be played in less than or equal to the total duration represented by the random number.

For example, if the random value 5.2 is generated then the first three notes should be played because their total duration is 3.8 which is less than 5.2; if the random value 8.7 is generated then the first six notes should be played because their total duration is equal to 8.7.

```
import arb.soundcipher.*;
SoundCipher midi;

String[] note = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#",
                 "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};
float[] volume = {80,  100,  75,   43,  40,  81,  100,
                  60,   90,  30,   75,  52};
float[] duration = {1.3,   2, 0.5,    3, 0.9,   1, 0.25,
                    0.6, 1.5,   3, 1.25,   2};

void setup() {
  size(200,200);
  midi = new SoundCipher(this);
  int i = (int) random(note.length);
  midi.playNote(MIDIValue(note[i]),volume[i],duration[i]);
}

float MIDIValue(String aNote) {
  float noteMIDIValue = 0.0;
  int i;
  for (i =0; i < note.length && !note[i].equals(aNote) ; i++); 
  if(i < note.length) {
     noteMIDIValue = i+60;
  }
  return noteMIDIValue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For getting the random number you'll want to use `Math.random()`, this generates a random number between 0 and 1. To make it so that it generates a random double between 0 and 10, you'll want to do that times 10, so `Math.random() * 10`.

To make it play the required notes, you can "chip away" an element from your `duration` list at this random number, until doing so would leave it below the next duration.

A code example could look like this:

```
    float randomNumber = (float)Math.random() * 10f;
    int currentNote = 0;
    while(randomNumber > duration[currentNote]){
        randomNumber -= duration[currentNote]; // "Chip away" duration
        midi.playNote(MIDIValue(note[currentNote]),volume[currentNote],duration[currentNote]); // Play the note
        currentNote++; // Try out the next note
    }
```